# How to know which type should getter have in java project on Eclipse? (It is unknown to me)

Tags: java, set, javabeans, getter

I have a set of a set variable that (I guess) contains Strings returned from a query (that's all I know and need to retrieve) defined in this way:

```
private Set<Set<Type_A>> variable_A;
variable_A = query.getVarA();
```

Now I need a getter that returns an array of these Strings, and tried with the code below with no success, due to the its return type I guess.

I can't also debug my code because it's a javabean used by a jsp file and Eclipse won't give me a clue on how to proceed. Is there a way to fix this? I tried with `public void getVarA()` and `public ArrayList<String> getVarA()`

```
public Set<Axiom> getVarA() {
    Iterator itr1 = variable_A.iterator();
    Set set;
    while(itr1.hasNext()) { 
        set = (HashSet)itr1.next();
    }                 
    return set; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be something like this, though I'm not entirely sure what is it your trying to achieve. Hope this helps ;)

```
public class Foo<T> {

    private final Set<Set<T>> setsOfSets = new HashSet<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Foo<String> tester = new Foo<>();
        Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B"));
        Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("C", "D"));
        Set<String> set3 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("E", "F"));
        tester.addRecord(set1);
        tester.addRecord(set2);
        tester.addRecord(set3);

        System.out.println(tester.getFirstSet());
        System.out.println(tester.getFirstSet());
        System.out.println(tester.getFirstSet());
        System.out.println(tester.getFirstSet());
    }

    public void addRecord(Set<T> record) {
        setsOfSets.add(record);
    }

    public List<T> getFirstSet() {
        Iterator<Set<T>> iterator = setsOfSets.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            final Set<T> set = iterator.next();
            iterator.remove();
            return new ArrayList<>(set);
        }
        //if there are no sets present
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this works for a set of simple Strings like you did, but I'm not entirely sure about the content of the sets (probably it is defined in another file but I can't access to that because I compile with Maven that takes care of many stuff like missing libraries and other cases.. Your code let me understand a little more of sets as I'm trying to learn how to manage them, but doesn't quite solve my problem sadly :\

Comment: My example should work with any type defined when creating
final Foo<String> tester = new Foo<>();
Can you show me a use case for your class, when you call the method 
public Set<Type_A> getVarA(). When class instance that will contain your set of sets you define the type. Which should be retrieved it could easily contain some other POJO.

Answer (score 0):

What your `getVarA` does is that is iterates through `variable_a` and returns last item of this iteration as a [raw Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

If you are using java8 you can use streams and their flatMap operation to collect all values of subsets into a single set.

```
public Set<Type_A> getVarA() {             
    return variable_A.stream().flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Otherwise you can just iterate with foreach and return collected result.

```
public Set<Type_A> getVarA() {
    Set<Type_A> result = new HashSet<>();
    for (Set<Type_A> subset : variable_A) {
        result.addAll(subset);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Tried your code but got an error in the 'for' line: ~~~~
 `incompatible types: java.util.Set<org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.TypeA> cannot be converted to java.util.Set<java.lang.String>` ~~~~ and also some other errors about: `no suitable method found for addAll(java.util.Set<java.lang.String>)` - - - EDIT: same error with both suggestions

Comment: That is because you have a Set<TypeA> and you are trying to convert it to Set<String>. If you have a Set<TypeA> and you call its addAll method its argument has to be another Set<TypeA>.

Comment: I edited the foreach example to remore misplaced String type.

Comment: Ok, I can compile now with maven and launch the webapp I'm modifing with the getter in your code and that's quite good, but when I use getVarA in the jsp file that recalls the javabean I get this: `[SubClassOf( )]`. What to do now? It should be strings for what I know!

Comment: Can you post the class you are trying to get from sets?

Comment: No I cannot, that's my problem ^^ Have to find an alternative way to get it, if possible